# jqueryui datepicker not showing all years in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

.
Hello,

I'm using jqueryui's datepicker, and it works great but there's a problem.
The list of year is not complete, for example it only show 10 years. If I want to go 10 years back I have to click on the first year and then click again to select one year

This are my settings:

```
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional["es"] );
    $("#birth_date").datepicker(
    {
        shortYearCutoff: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: "-70Y", 
        maxDate: "-15Y" 
    });
```

The first time it show this range 1997 to 1987, if I want to set 1960 then I have to click 2  times and it bothers sometimes.

What I want to know is if theres a way to show the entire year list, from 1942 to 1997

Thanks in advance

Javier

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [yearRange](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange) option too. MaxDate and MinDate only validates the date chosen. Year range modifies the visible years.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional["es"] );
    $("#birth_date").datepicker(
    {
        shortYearCutoff: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: "-70Y", 
        maxDate: "-15Y",
        yearRange: "1942:1997"
    });
```

Comment: it was difficult to decide the right answer, but thanks both of you

Comment: @JavierQQ23 Now that you have chosen you could always upvote the other.

Answer (score 7):

You want to add the year  range option:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/NAuEx/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional["es"] );
    $("#birth_date").datepicker(
    {
        shortYearCutoff: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: "-70Y", 
        maxDate: "-15Y",
         yearRange: "1900:2010" 
    });

});
​
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting a more dynamic range will look like this in your case

```
yearRange: "-70Y:-15Y"
```